# Plotting x-axis values at intervals

Tags: r, plot

I will like to plot some data, with the x-axis data plotted at intervals

X:

```
50.0000
100.5467
689.7431
1559.8025
1000.9365
10.9095
```

Y:

```
-0.0596123270783229
 0.644158691971081
-0.433854284204926
-0.365746109442603
 0.566685929975495
 0.398462720589891
```

Function:

```
plotM<- function( dat, m ) {
  plot(data$X, data$Y,
       log="x", pch=20, cex=0.7,
       col = ifelse( data$Y < m, "red", "black" ), 
       xlab = "Y", ylab = expression(Log[2]~Fold~Change))
}
```

Function call:

```
plotM(dat, .05)
```

How can I plot the data with the following sequence in x-axis:

```
10, 100, 1000, 2000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a plot with no axes then add them manually.

Using some example data

```
x = 10^(0:3)
y = 0:3
```

We plot `x` and `y` and specify no axis are to be plotted:

```
plot(x, y, log="x", axes=FALSE, frame=TRUE)
```

Then add on the x and y axis manually

```
## See ?axis for more details
axis(1, 10^(0:3), 10^(0:3))
axis(2)
```

Alternatively, we can be a bit more fancy with the axis labels to get

```
axis(1, 10^(0:3),  c(expression(10^0), 
                     expression(10^1), 
                     expression(10^2), 
                     expression(10^3)))
```

to get

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to solve the actual question asked - with the step from 10>100>1000>2000

Comment: Change `10^(0:3)` to `c(10, 100, 1000, 2000)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this... I have used ggplot2, much used graphical package of R.

It will create x axis on log scale using ggplot..

```
ggplot(data = data) + geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) + scale_x_log10()
```

This is how results will look like...

[image]